# Dual space of L infty space

Tags: functional-analysis

The Dual space of L infty space is not L1 ,are there some example to show this?
I am going to use rieze representation thm,but it can not be used because p= $\infty$.

Comment: If the dual of a Banach space is separable, then the original space must be separable.